# HighCharts add space to Y-Axis Label gutter

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have created a chart using the HighCharts javascript library, the problem I have is that my y-Axis labels are cut by the Y-Axis vertical line. I would like to add more space in the y-axis label gutter area to allow for the labels to be fully visible and so i can add some annotations to the in that area, see image below:

[image]

Ideally I would like to add 40px, to the Y-Axis gutter. I have read through the api reference and tried using "yAxis.labels.padding", "yAxis.margin" and "yAxis.offset".

My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">

    #container {
      height: 400px;
      width: 350px;
    }

    .highcharts-tick{display: none;}

    .highcharts-grid-line{opacity: 0.2}

    
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/accessibility.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id=container2></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  
  const options = {
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#1B191B', // Background Color
        type: 'line',
        zoomType: "",
       
    },
    rangeSelector : {
        enabled: false,
        selected : 2,
        inputEnabled: false
      },

    title: {
      text: 'APPLE INC', // Title of the Chart
      align: 'left',
      style: {
            color: '#dedbde',   // Custom CSS for the title
            fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
    },
    scrollbar: { enabled: false },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false 
    },
    yAxis: {
    lineWidth: 2,
    tickWidth: 1,
    labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#dedbde' 
                },
                align: 'right',
                

            },
         
    opposite: true, 
    offset: -1 
  },

  xAxis: {
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#dedbde' 
                }
            },
            gridLineWidth: 1,            
        },
     navigator: {
        enabled: false 
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
      data: [],
      type: 'areaspline',
      threshold: null,
      color: '#5861B3', 
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
      },
      
      fillColor: {
        linearGradient: {
          x1: 0,
          y1: 0,
          x2: 0,
          y2: 1
        },
        stops: [
          [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
          [1, Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
        ]
      }
    }]
  }
  const url = 'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-c.json'
  const chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', options)
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    chart.series[0].setData(data)
      // Execute callback
    if (chart.options.chart.events && chart.options.chart.events.dataLoad) {
      const dataLoad = chart.options.chart.events.dataLoad.bind(chart)
      dataLoad(data)
    }
  })
})

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Been banging my head around this for while, but I cant seem to figure it out any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Highstock, the yAxis is inverted by default, so aligning the labels is reversed as well.

The only thing you need to change is setting `yAxis.labels.align` to `'left'`.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/10ae8g9d/